# Unable to delete image from gallery after capture in Moto G 2nd gen

Tags: android, android-studio, media

I need to capture image via my android app, immediately after which I delete image from camera gallery, and store it in my app directory.

This works fine in all android devices with variety of Android vesions (from 4.1.2 to 5.1)

But fails on Motorola 2nd gen phone.
My phone (Moto G) has 2 options to store captured images:
Phone and sdcard.

But images are not getting deleted from the path.
The path is also correct!

Please help.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will have much better luck in getting help if you provide [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, nobody has any idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the correct permission in your AndroidManifest.xml ?
Maybe images are stored in sdcard ?

Something like `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`